# Creating dynamic tables from JSON data with angular-directives

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I have the following JSON object:

```
[{
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Foosie",
        "terms": [{
                "term": 24,
                "monthly": 190.09
            },
            {
                "term": 27,
                "monthly": 179.6
            },
            {
                "term": 30,
                "monthly": 178.78
            },
            {
                "term": 33,
                "monthly": 178.06
            },
            {
                "term": 36,
                "monthly": 171.11
            },
            {
                "term": 39,
                "monthly": 215.36
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 35,
        "name": "Barrie",
        "terms": [{
                "term": 24,
                "monthly": 199.61
            },
            {
                "term": 27,
                "monthly": 188.05
            },
            {
                "term": 30,
                "monthly": 186.37
            },
            {
                "term": 33,
                "monthly": 184.95
            },
            {
                "term": 36,
                "monthly": 177.41
            },
            {
                "term": 39,
                "monthly": 220.85
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "Boosie",
        "terms": [{
                "term": 24,
                "monthly": 290.04
            },
            {
                "term": 27,
                "monthly": 287.01
            },
            {
                "term": 36,
                "monthly": 257.07
            },
            {
                "term": 39,
                "monthly": 245.85
            },
            {
                "term": 42,
                "monthly": 241.45
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to create a table with both vertical and horizontal tables. `(Vertical = names [Boosie, Foosie, Barrie], Horizontal = terms [24,27,...]`

Monthly is a button `<button (click)="selectPayment(id, term)"></button>` which passes the id and term of the selected cell.

jsfiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/34k8ytrk/ 
[NOTE: this was done with a `<table></table>` for quick demo purposes, your response doesn't have to be a table]

I know that I need to keep track of both name and term, as monthly depends on them, however I am trapped in a  hell and am having trouble figuring it out.
I understand that I might have to do some manipulation to the data in order to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your quote block to show how you want the table to look with the real data? So instead of using `name1`, `name2`, `monthly`, please visualize the table with real data you have in the json. This will make it clearer

Comment: @borislemke I am building one now

Comment: @borislemke edited, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34k8ytrk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*table.component.html*

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>(blank)</td>
        <!-- assuming all terms are the same, just take the first of the object -->
        <td *ngFor="let head of uniqueHeaders">{{head}}</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let bank of banks; let i = index">
        <td>{{bank.name}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let head of uniqueHeaders">{{getColumnData(head, i)}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*table.component.ts*

```
class BankDatabase {

    banks: BankData[] // your bank data

    get uniqueHeaders(): number[] {

      // We want a unique array of numbers for the header
      let _uniqueHeader = []


      this.banks.forEach((bank) => {
          bank.terms.forEach((term) => {
          // Append the term if it has not been added yet
          if (!_uniqueHeader.includes(term.term))
            _uniqueHeader.push(term.term)
        })
      })

      // This should return a unique array of all terms combined
      return _uniqueHeader
    }

    // head is the currently iterated column
    // i is the index of the bank (in your example 0 - 2)
    getColumnData(head, i): string {

      const matchingData = this.banks[i].terms.find(_term => _term.term === head)
      // If matching data found, return it's monthly value, else return empty string
      return matchingData && matchingData.monthly || ''
    }
}
```

Is this what you want? `banks` is the `json` data you have.

**NOTE** that I am using a getter function to flatten the headers array, this is sloppy, you should optimize by saving the flattened data into a property instead and get it from there whenever you need it. You may also need to take an extra step to sort the array as in my example, the array happens to be sorted from the sample data given.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OhLzW3YoxpLtnNkUHMJ9?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Please do not simply copy paste this answer, let me know if you don't understand anything. Learn!

Comment: Some issues...
1. All terms are not the same, see Foosie vs Boosie, they have different terms. 
2. Boosie doesn't have terms for 30 or 33 months, these cells need to be skipped...

Comment: @Moshe ok, that's easy. as for `name` and `bankName` can there be other names? You should really try to make these consistent

Comment: I changed it from bankName to just name, copypasta

Comment: can you compare my jsfiddle with your plunkr to see the differences?

Comment: @Moshe I've updated the answer and my plunker. Let me know if I need to explain anything.

Comment: we're getting closer...

in the old plunker we did:
                    `<td *ngFor="let term of bank.terms"><button (click)="processSelection(term, bank.bankName)">{{term.monthly}}</button></td>`


How can I pass Bank Name and term details to function with new wrapper functions?

                   `<td *ngFor="let head of uniqueHeaders">{{head}}</td>`

Comment: @Moshe I'm sorry, I'm not really following you there. Could you make it more obvious in your jsfiddle? What you want to do?

Comment: @Moshe but do you understand everything we did there?

Comment: yes I understand almost everything. See this plunkr for what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/NKqBURfcdBUJeSsMu4YV?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: your plunker is already good, but again, you used `bank.bankName` instead of `bank.name`. Be consistent :D

Comment: @Moshe nice! Glad I could be of help. Good luck with your project!